# Revert a large number of files in Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

I was working together with two coworkers on a project, and we exchanged the data via Dropbox (nothing critical, so we could use Dropbox). The problem now is: One of them got the encryption virus, and all of our files are encrypted. But we can set all the files back to a non-encrypted state thanks to Dropbox. Is there a faster way for reverting all files to the last known file status than to select all files separately and switch them back?